# My Table of content is not accurate. The pages are numbered wrongly

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my thesis and I just noticed there are some problems with my toc. First the list of tables shows only one table, however I have about six tables in my paper. I also just noticed the table of contents has not updated the pages, so the sections and subsections have the wrong numbering. I realised that my toc doesn't recognize any page after page 29, and that's the reason the tables and figures on pages after page 29 doesn't show. Also that's the reason the section pages have not updated. I've tried to change the code the problem remains.

Comment: the toc shows the values from the previous run so if you run latex again they should get back in sync. If they do not then you have an error somewhere but you would need to show a small example for us to guess where the error is.

Comment: Have a look at the log file and search for "error" in this file. It is very likely that it tells you what might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I couldn't solve this and my deadline was today so I deleted the table of contents and manually typed it in word and then inserted it in my PDF. It was very frustrating trying to solve it because I didn't know what was wrong